# PlayFramework 2.6 shutdown hook

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

Play Framework 2.6
Mongo 3.6.2
Mongo Scala Driver 2.2.0
I want to drop MongoDB database, every time when I shutdown the application. I have the following code, implementing lifecycle stop hook, but when SIGTERM is send to the applicatin it's do not drop the database. What am I doing wrong ?

```
@Singleton
class Repo  @Inject() (lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) {

  val codecRegistry: CodecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[MyCollection]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY )
  val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient()
  val database: MongoDatabase =   mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb").withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry)

 .......

 lifecycle.addStopHook { () => {
     database.drop().toFuture()
       }
     }   
   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the `drop()` is implemented, but I'm guessing that - instead of using `toFuture()`, you may need to make a blocked call with a timeout.

Comment: Are you sure the shutdown hook is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the database drop `Future` to complete (and close the `MongoClient`):

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

...

lifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
  val result = Await.result(database.drop().toFuture(), Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
  Future.successful(mongoClient.close())
}
```